# Experimental design in R: balanced incomplete block design

Tags: r, matlab, latin-square, experimental-design

I would like to generate a matrix to plan an experiment.

- I have 6 individuals and 6 treatments delivered in 6 days.
- I can use 1 individual per week (6 weeks of 6 days in total = 36 days of testings with 6 treatments a day).
- Every day, I will test 6 treatments on the individual in a random order.
  An individual should not start with the same treatment any day of the week.

For example:

```
Monday: A C D B E F
Tuesday: C E A B F D
...
```

- If possible, different individuals should not have the same order that the others.
- I would like to take into account order treatment; that is each pair of treatments following each other should be repeated as equally often as possible to avoid "carryover" (sequence and order) effects.
  I am working with R at the moment but could also work with MATLAB.

I have tried to work out a design with the package "agricolae" and the package "crossdes" but no success so far. My ideas were to use a balanced incomplete block design. An example of one of my code follows.

```
> trt <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" )
> k <- 6
> outdesign<- design.bib (trt, k, seed=0)
Error in md[i, bi] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you're desired output is 6 treatment orders, selected randomly, and preferably all different? I'm not sure I understand what you mean by your second point.

Comment: I would like to take into effect the carry over effect. The carry over effect is the possibility that effects gained from a previous treatment may still be present and, therefore, be carried over in the next treatment. I would like a design that balance for this.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong function. You want a complete block design (design.rcbd), not an incomplete one. The incomplete block design will create blocks where only some of the treatments are included. Therefore, for design.bib, k < length(trt).

EDIT: This will give you 6 subjects for 6 days. Forcing each day to start with a different treatment for each subject is more involved than I have time for at the moment, but perhaps someone else will answer you before I get to to it.

```
trt <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" )
N <- 6
days <- 6

outdesign<-as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=N*length(trt),ncol=days+1))
names(outdesign)<-c("Subj", "Day1", "Day2", "Day3", "Day4", "Day5", "Day6")
outdesign$Subj<-rep(1:6,each=length(trt))
for (i in 1:days) {
  outdesign[,i+1]<- design.rcbd(trt, N, seed=0,first=TRUE)$book$trt
}

   Subj Day1 Day2 Day3 Day4 Day5 Day6
1     1    E    F    D    C    C    C
2     1    C    E    E    F    F    E
3     1    D    C    B    A    E    D
4     1    B    D    F    D    A    A
5     1    A    B    C    B    D    F
6     1    F    A    A    E    B    B
7     2    D    C    F    A    F    F
8     2    B    E    B    C    E    B
9     2    C    D    E    E    D    A
10    2    A    F    A    F    B    E
11    2    F    A    D    B    C    D
12    2    E    B    C    D    A    C
13    3    B    C    C    A    B    F
14    3    A    A    E    F    E    E
15    3    C    E    F    B    A    B
16    3    E    B    A    C    F    A
17    3    F    F    B    D    C    C
18    3    D    D    D    E    D    D
19    4    F    C    F    D    F    E
20    4    D    B    A    E    B    D
21    4    B    F    D    A    A    F
22    4    C    A    B    B    D    B
23    4    E    E    E    C    C    C
24    4    A    D    C    F    E    A
25    5    D    E    F    A    A    F
26    5    A    D    E    E    E    B
27    5    C    C    C    D    D    E
28    5    E    F    B    C    C    C
29    5    B    A    A    F    B    A
30    5    F    B    D    B    F    D
31    6    F    F    A    F    C    F
32    6    A    D    E    E    D    B
33    6    C    B    C    D    A    A
34    6    B    C    F    C    F    C
35    6    E    E    B    A    E    D
36    6    D    A    D    B    B    E
```

Comment: Thank you! My problem with that design is: for example, it can happen that treatment C is first in order in day 2 and day 4 of the week. Also, this design doesn't include the factor individuals (6 individuals to test, which means 6 times 6 days). I hope that make sense?

Comment: You aren't going to find a single function to do what you want, but you can use if statements and loops to make this one produce what you want. I'll provide an edit shortly.